how to manage collision in flutter flame when multiple objects of the same type collide?
I am trying to make a bubble shooter demo that has 3 types of bubbles (fish,dog and cat).
They are all circle components.
For example when i launch a dog bubble to a group of bubbles it explodes all the dog bubbles that exist in the screen,
is there a way to make bubbles explodes only the ones that are close to the one who got hit by the launch bubble?
@override
void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {     
  super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
  if (other is DogBubble) {
    if (position.distanceTo(other.position) <= radius + other.radius) {
      removeFromParent();
    }
  }
}

I've tried a couple of ways to remove only the one who got hit and other remove all the dogs bubble in the screen.
I expect that when a bubble gets hit all of the bubbles that close to it will be removed.

If your DogBubbles are in the world you can query them and do the check (if they have another component as a parent, use that one to query for them).
Also, use onCollisionStart instead of onCollision, since you're not observing continues collisions.
@override
void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {     
  super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
  if (other is DogBubble) {
    for(final bubble in world.query<DogBubble>()) {
      if (position.distanceTo(bubble.position) <= radius + bubble.radius) {
        removeFromParent();
      }
    }
  }
}

If you don't have access to your world in the component, add the HasWorldReference mixin to the component and it will provide you with the world variable inside of the component.

hey thank you for the answer
i have a question
when the radius of the CircleHitBox is bigger than the radius of the CircleComponent the collisoin is being trigger right when the game lauches.
And it makes all the dog bubbles that are together to get removed so only the ones that are alone left along the ones who are not dog bubble.
and if i make it the same as the radius of the CircleComponent then when the bubble i launch hit dog bubble it removes only the ones that got hit.
any idea on how to approach this problem?
thanks in advance.

This is better to discuss on our Discord, because I don't think this will take only one message back and forth. So you can mark this answer as correct (we try to have all Flame tagged questions answered), and then you can join our discord here: https://discord.com/invite/pxrBmy4
